# sumar datos filtrados en un datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview, visual

Hola tengo un pequeño problema  tengo un **DataGrid** cargado de **MySql** que lo extraigo por rango de fechas y me muestra la suma  de la columna cantidad
[image: DataGrid]

pero ahora que filtro por segunda vez con el **combobox** con esta función:

```
 BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
 bs.DataSource = TablaProductos.DataSource;
 bs.Filter = String.Format("CONVERT(categoria, 'System.String') = '{0}'", comboBox1.Text);
 TablaProductos.DataSource = bs;
```

hago la suma otra vez pero me da la cantidad de todos los datos y no solo los filtrados me pueden orientar.
Gracias

Comment: ¿Como haces la suma de la Columna cantidad?

Comment: con esta función:

            for (int i = 0; i < TablaProductos.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {

                sumas += Convert.ToDouble(TablaProductos.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value);
            }
            label5.Text ="$"+sumas.ToString();

Comment: Por lo que veo a el label no le estas pasando un nuevo dato... Si mandas a llamar nuevamente al Metodo para volver a suma r?.